# Finding eigenvalues and eigenvectors after SVD?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, svd

The elements represent the SVD of a square matrix and its transpose. I'm confused on how this works for a matrix within a matrix. Computing the characteristic polynomial doesn't seem to get me anywhere, because I just end up with $\lambda^2=U\Sigma V^tV\Sigma U^t$.

Comment: **Hint** You might want to look at the characteristic polynomial of that block matrix, and see where that gets you. Then you can report your progress by clicking "Edit" just below your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us take the following notations

$$M=U\Sigma V^T\tag{1}$$ and

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}0 & M\\ M^T & 0\end{bmatrix}\tag{2}$$

We have the following decomposition:

$$\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}0 & U\Sigma V^T \\ V\Sigma U^T & 0\end{bmatrix}}_A=\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}U\Sigma & 0\\0& V\Sigma \end{bmatrix}}_P \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}0&\Sigma\\ \Sigma&0\end{bmatrix}}_B\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}\Sigma^{-1}U^{-1} & 0\\0& \Sigma^{-1}V^{-1}\end{bmatrix}}_{P^{-1}}\tag{3}$$

The eigenvalues of $B$ are known to be the eigenvalues of $\Sigma$ (i.e., the singular values) and their opposites (see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/484209)).

Therefore, $A$ has the same eigenvalues as $B$.

Dealing with eigenvectors, as (1) can be written in two ways,

$$MV=U\Sigma \ \ \text{and} \ \ M^TU=V\Sigma\tag{4}$$

which is equivalent to say that, for any $k$,

$$MV_k=\sigma_kU_k \ \ \text{and} \ \ M^TU_k=\sigma_kV_k\tag{5}$$

(we call $U_k,V_k$ the $k$th column of $U,V$ resp. and $\sigma_k$ the $k$-th singular value).

Therefore, using (5), it is easy to check that the eigenvectors of $A$ are:

$$\binom{U_k}{V_k}\ \ \text{and} \ \ \binom{\ \ \ U_k}{-V_k}$$

resp. associated with eigenvalues $\sigma_k$ and $-\sigma_k$.

Comment: No comment ? Is this answer  understandable ?

Comment: Yes, I had to think about it some, thank you! That helped clear things up.

Answer (score 0):

Let $U\Sigma V^t$ and $\Sigma$ both be $n \times n$. Let $A$ be the block matrix.

Zero is an eigenvalue of $A$ if and only if zero is an eigenvalue of $U\Sigma V^t$. (Why?)

For nonzero eigenvalues, using the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement#Properties), we can compute the characteristic polynomial $p(\lambda)$ for $\lambda \ne 0$
\begin{align}
\det(A - \lambda I) &= \det(-\lambda I_n) \det(-\lambda I_n - V\Sigma U^t(-\lambda^{-1} I_n) U\Sigma V^t)
\\
& = (-\lambda)^n \det (-\lambda I_n - (-\lambda^{-1}) V\Sigma^2 V^t)
\\
&= (-\lambda)^n \prod_{i=1}^n (-\lambda + \sigma_i^2/\lambda)
\end{align}